# How to allow adaptive injection of services following the repository pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, service, repository-pattern

I want to allow the user to specify which services my WPF application should connect to. In the current setup, I'm using the repository pattern, and inject a single service into the repository on start-up:

```
public MyRepository(IDataContext service)
{
        _service = service;
        _service.DataReceived += ServiceOnDataReceived;          
}
```

What I would like to do now is to change this setup to allow the user to specify which services that are injected into the repository in run-time (note that all services send the same type of data).

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an IDataContextContainer, like this:

```
public interface IDataContextContainer
{
  event Action DataContextChanging;
  event Action DataContextChanged;
  IDataContext Current { get; }
}
```

Receiving this in your constructor, you could subscribe to the events on Current, and subscribe to the DataContextChanged event (fired after datacontext changes), to keep your repository updated to the current service, and to DataContextChanging (fired before datacontext changes), to unsubscribe the repository from the events of the old datacontext.